# О запятых при однородных членах, соединенных и союзами, и бессоюзной связью

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, союзы, однородные-члены, запятые

Правило Розенталя гласит: "Запятая ставится между однородными членами также в том случае, когда только часть их связана повторяющимися союзами, а остальные соединяются бессоюзной связью, например: *Он слеп, упрям, нетерпелив, и легкомыслен, и кичлив.*"

Вопрос: при каком минимальном количестве однородных членов, соединенных союзами, работает данное правило? И зависит ли действие данного правила от места в предложении таких однородных членов?

(Для наглядности вопроса — примеры:

Дети разглядывали высокие кипарисовые деревья, заботливо постриженные газоны, фонтаны, скамеечки, **и маленькие кафе с верандами**, запрещающие знаки.

Дети разглядывали высокие кипарисовые деревья, заботливо постриженные газоны, фонтаны, скамеечки, запрещающие знаки **и маленькие кафе с верандами.**

Дети разглядывали высокие кипарисовые деревья, заботливо постриженные газоны, фонтаны, скамеечки, **и запрещающие знаки,** **и маленькие кафе с верандами.**

Дети разглядывали высокие кипарисовые деревья, **и запрещающие знаки,** заботливо постриженные газоны, фонтаны, скамеечки,  **и маленькие кафе с верандами.**

Дети смеялись, бегали по газону, **и бросались опавшими листьями**, веселились, играли в свои игры.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Союз И должен повторяться **хотя бы дважды**, тогда ставятся запятые между всеми однородными членами.

2) После первого союза И **все последующие однородные члены также имеют союз И**.

3) **Если это правило не соблюдается,** то возможны два варианта: а) союз И соединяет придаточные в группы. В этом случае надо проверять обоснованность такого соединения, а также правильность постановки запятых между группами. б) предложение неправильно построено, нужно изменить количество и расстановку союзов.

Эти правила соответствуют **перечислительной интонации** предложения при постановке запятых, при этом  однородные члены могут **объединяться в группы** 
 (интонационные фразы в устной речи).

**Часть предложение исправлено:**

(1) Дети разглядывали высокие кипарисовые деревья, заботливо постриженные газоны, фонтаны, скамеечки, и маленькие кафе с верандами,  **и** запрещающие знаки.

(2) Дети разглядывали высокие кипарисовые деревья, заботливо постриженные газоны, фонтаны, скамеечки, запрещающие знаки и маленькие кафе с верандами.

(3) Дети разглядывали высокие кипарисовые деревья, заботливо постриженные газоны, фонтаны, скамеечки, и запрещающие знаки, и маленькие кафе с верандами.

(4) Дети разглядывали высокие кипарисовые деревья и запрещающие знаки, заботливо постриженные газоны, фонтаны, скамеечки и маленькие кафе с верандами.

(5) Дети смеялись, бегали по газону и бросались опавшими листьями, веселились, играли в свои игры.

Comment: Голосую за, хотя сомневаюсь в корректности (4) с точки зрения семантики. По какому признаку деревья и знаки, скамеечки и кафе выделены в отдельные группы?

Comment: Я исправляла только форму, не касаясь семантики, так как задание учебное.  В реальных текстах группировка должна быть обоснованной. В заданном примере лучше обойтись вообще без группировки, как в первом предложении.